# The Coding Assistance of Node.js and NPM can not enable in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm

The Coding Assistance of Node.js and NPM can not enable in WebStorm.

In the WebStorm -> File -> Default Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I want to enable the Coding Assistance, but it can not be enabled.

My WebStorm version is `WebStorm 2016.2`.

---

**EDIT-1**

The `/usr/local/bin/node` exists, because you can see the `8.9.1` in the snapsot.

and I also check the version of it:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/node -v
v8.9.1
```

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/node` exist and is it accessible/executable by the current user?  `./usr/local/bin/node -v` in terminal should answer this with node version

Comment: @Deryck See my EDIT-1.

Comment: how are you launching webstorm?

Comment: You are doing that for `Default Preferences` (will affect only future new projects; some stuff cannot be applied here). Do it for actual **current project** Preferences instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unfortunately WebStorm 2016.x doesn't support recent Node.js versions. **Node.js core** library can't be enabled when using Node.js 8.x, debugging won't work, etc. You have to either downgrade Node.js to v.4.x or upgrade WebStorm to the most recent version

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there are some people who cannot check the coding assistance for Nodejs checkbox in webstorm. I am one of them, I have tried to enable it in n no.of different ways but nothing worked. I think there should be some issue with webstorm versions.
So, I have tried the below steps and luckily now i am able to get coding assistance. if you want to get coding assistance while working on nodejs file.

## steps to follow:

1. create a project with npm init
2. create a file inside the directory like app.js

Hope this helps. Now you can see the coding assistance for Nodejs though checkbox for coding assistance not works. :) Happy coding

OR

update your node js to above 12.0 versions

Comment: +1 for the solution, but this is a bug; you should probably have reported it. I'll try make time over the weekend to report it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem but with WebStorm 2023.1.1, and after an hour I find a solution. I changed the IDE style from the new to the old one. And the check box for enabling the Node.js code assistance is active now. I marked that and it's download dependency and works correctly.

After this fix, I reload the new IDE style gain and check the option. it's still work.

So the problem must be related to the new Webstorm style.

Comment: This stopped working after I updated WebStorm to the latest version and your solution didn't work for me. WebStorm 2023.2 #WS-232.8660.143, built on July 21, 2023. node 20.2.0 installed using nvm.